# Maintaining python flask sessions from an ajax call

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, session, flask

I am using flask sessions in my program to maintain all dynamic information .I have hosted my service on local host.

```
from flask import Flask,make_response,render_template, request, jsonify,json,jsonify,send_from_directory,session
from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='test'  
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'


@app.route('/getAnswer')    
@cross_origin() 
def getAnswer():
    userQuery = request.args.get("query") 


    session['username']="testuser"
    session['userid']="Utkj3YC"
    reply=askquestion(userQuery,session)
    print "giving response : ",str(reply)
    answer=str(reply)

    return jsonify(response=answer,id="1",status="suc",dialog="initial")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',processes=True,debug=True,port=8000)
```

This is my flask service and this works fine when i am testing the same from postman restclient. The postman requests are maintaining the same session variables.

[image]

The problem is when i integrated this service with my UI. the ajax request every time resets the flask session variable because of which i am unable to maintain the session.
My ajax call is as follows

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/getAnswer",
        method: 'GET',

        data: { query: query,dialog:dialog },
        success: function(data) { 


         var $chatBox = $('#botReplyDiv').clone().prop('id',"botdiv"+data.id);
         var $loading = $('.loader');
         $chatBox.css("display", "block");
         var ul  = document.createElement('ul');
         console.log(data.response);
         var resp=data.response;
         var li=document.createElement('li');
         li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.response));

         ul.appendChild(li);

         }
         });
```

I also tried adding this in the ajax request.

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
  }
```

But the problem still persists. every time a new session is created in flask. But the same code when i do with POSTMAN ,it is persisting the same session. What is the change that i have to do to make the ajax call retain the same session in every request ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i was using http://locahost:8000/getAnswer in my client side code. I changed it ti http://127.0.0.1:8000/getAnswer and it is working fine now.